# need guidance on how to create a questionaire for android

Tags: android

I have a task to create 10 questions where a user should be able to input the answer by using a touch keypad. The user should be able to cycle through questions by pressing a button called "N" 
 Once the the user answers all of the questions a total score out of 10 would be displayed.

Im not asking for an answer but how to approach such a task.
So far ive created a keypad consisting of numbers and i can get 1 question to work and display whether the user entered correct or incorrect information but trying to get more then 1 question to work is messing up.
I had a thought and know that i can create 10 seperate activities for 10 questions but thats slightly crazy.

Can someone give me guidance on how to approach such as task 
note im pretty new to android.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All views have a visibility attribute (android:visibility); what would look nice is every time the user presses next is to simply hide the old view and make the next one show up (Can even add a fading transition to make it look fun as well)

In XML you can set them all to android:visibility="gone" to begin with, and then in your code, set it to objectName.setVisibility(0) to make it visible, and objectName.setVisibility(8) to hide it completely again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach (not necessarily the best):

*Wherever your question is (hopefully a TextView), get a reference of it in your activity.
*When the user answers a question, output if it was correct or not (A toast?)
*Change the TextView to the next question

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically add and remove views. You could create an empty view with just a linear layout then add and modify the existing views as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing it as a native Android app? A web-app (HTML, Javascript) could do what you're asking, and could be turned into an native app with embedded webkit view.